# Showing wrong value after setProperty in a Traver

Tags: java, neo4j

The following is a neo4j graph with two kind of edges. First we traverse the edges(BFS) and then normalize value of properties of each kind of edge. But while retrieving the values in a different loop Wrong values are getting printed.

This looks very much strange. May be I'm missing something. It will be of great help if any 
one makes me correct OR suggest me a better way to avoid this error. Thanks in advance :)

```
package org.neo4j.examples;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Path;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.traversal.Evaluator;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.traversal.Evaluators;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.traversal.TraversalDescription;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.traversal.Traverser;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.traversal.Uniqueness;
import org.neo4j.kernel.Traversal;

public class MyNeo4jExpt {
    public enum RelTypes implements RelationshipType {
        CO_OCCURANCE, CAMPAIGN
    }

    private static final String MY_TRAVERSAL_DB = "target/my-traversal-db";
    private GraphDatabaseService graphDb;

    static Node shop1 = null;
    Node shop2 = null;
    Node shop3 = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MyNeo4jExpt matrix = new MyNeo4jExpt();
        matrix.setUp();
        matrix.normalizeRelations(shop1);
        matrix.shutdown();
    }

    public void setUp() {
        deleteFileOrDirectory(new File(MY_TRAVERSAL_DB));
        graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
                .newEmbeddedDatabase(MY_TRAVERSAL_DB);
        registerShutdownHook();
        createNodespace();
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        graphDb.shutdown();
    }

    public void createNodespace() {
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {

            // Create shop1
            shop1 = graphDb.createNode();
            shop1.setProperty("name", "FurnitureShop-1");

            // create shop2
            shop2 = graphDb.createNode();
            shop2.setProperty("name", "FurnitureShop-2");

            // create shop3
            shop3 = graphDb.createNode();
            shop3.setProperty("name", "FurnitureShop-3");

            // ////// connect shop1 to shop2 ///////
            Relationship rel = shop1.createRelationshipTo(shop2,
                    RelTypes.CO_OCCURANCE);
            rel.setProperty("coOccurence", (Double) 5.0);

            rel = shop1.createRelationshipTo(shop2, RelTypes.CAMPAIGN);
            rel.setProperty("furniture", (Double) 0.6);
            rel.setProperty("chair", (Double) 0.6);
            rel.setProperty("table", (Double) 0.6);
            // ///////////////////////////////////////

            // ///// connect shop1 to shop3///////
            rel = shop1.createRelationshipTo(shop3, RelTypes.CAMPAIGN);
            rel.setProperty("furniture", (Double) 0.7);
            rel.setProperty("sofa", (Double) 0.7);
            // ////////////////////////////////////////

            // ////// connect shop3 to shop2 ///////
            rel = shop3.createRelationshipTo(shop2, RelTypes.CO_OCCURANCE);
            rel.setProperty("coOccurence", (Double) 4.0);
            // ///////////////////////////////////////

            tx.success();
        }
    }

    // this function calls a BFS on the given node
    // and normalize relation properties w.r.t. the
    // right edge type (RelType)
    private Traverser normalizeRelations(final Node node) {
        Traverser friendsTraverser = null;
        HashMap<Relationship, Path> relHash = new HashMap<Relationship, Path>();
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            if (node == null) {
                System.out.println("\nNULL NODE\n");
                return null;
            }
            friendsTraverser = getFriends(node);

            if (friendsTraverser == null) {
                System.err.println("NULL TRAVERSER");
                return null;
            }

            HashMap<RelationshipType, Double> maxVal = new HashMap<RelationshipType, Double>();
            String temp = "";
            try (Transaction tx2 = graphDb.beginTx()) {
                for (Path friendPath : friendsTraverser) {
                    System.out.println("\nAt depth " + friendPath.length()
                            + " => " + friendPath.toString());
                    // output += friendPath.startNode().getProperty("name")+ " "
                    // ;
                    for (Relationship rel : friendPath.relationships()) {
                        temp = " " + rel.getStartNode().getProperty("name");
                        for (String name : rel.getPropertyKeys()) {
                            Double propVal = (Double) rel.getProperty(name);
                            temp += "---" + "(" + name + ", " + propVal + ")";
                            if ((maxVal.get(rel.getType()) == null)
                                    || (propVal > maxVal.get(rel.getType()))) {
                                maxVal.put(rel.getType(), propVal); // <----
                                                                    // Save the
                                                                    // Max Value
                                                                    // for
                                                                    // Particular
                                                                    // Rel Type
                            }
                        }

                        temp += "----" + rel.getEndNode().getProperty("name")
                                + "\n";

                    }
                    // numberOfFriends++;
                    System.out.println(temp);
                }
                tx2.success();
            }
            System.out.println("*************************************");
            System.out.println("**** Devide w.r.t maxVal = "
                    + maxVal.entrySet()
                    + "And Normalized Values Are:*************");
            System.out.println("*************************************");
            temp = "";
            for (Path friendPath : friendsTraverser) {
                System.out.println("\nAt depth " + friendPath.length() + " => "
                        + friendPath.toString());
                for (Relationship rel : friendPath.relationships()) {
                    temp = "" + rel.getStartNode().getProperty("name");
                    try (Transaction tx3 = graphDb.beginTx()) {
                        for (String propName : rel.getPropertyKeys()) {
                            Double propVal = (Double) rel.getProperty(propName)
                                    / maxVal.get(rel.getType());
                            rel.setProperty(propName, propVal);
                            temp += "---" + "(" + propName + ", "
                                    + rel.getProperty(propName) + ")";
                        }
                        tx3.success();
                    }
                    temp += "----" + rel.getEndNode().getProperty("name")
                            + "\n";
                }
                System.out.println(temp);
            }
            tx.success();

        }
        System.out
                .println("\n+++++++++++++NOW WRONG VALUES WILL BE PRINTED+++++++++++++++");
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            String temp = "";
            for (Path friendPath : friendsTraverser) {
                System.out.println("\nAt depth " + friendPath.length() + " => "
                        + friendPath.toString());
                for (Relationship rel : friendPath.relationships()) {
                    temp = " " + rel.getStartNode().getProperty("name");
                    for (String propName : rel.getPropertyKeys()) {
                        temp += "---" + "(" + propName + ", "
                                + rel.getProperty(propName) + ")";
                    }
                    temp += "----" + rel.getEndNode().getProperty("name")
                            + "\n";
                }
                System.out.println(temp);
            }
            tx.success();
        }
        return friendsTraverser;
    }

    // START SNIPPET: get-friends
    private static Traverser getFriends(final Node person) {
        TraversalDescription td = Traversal.description().breadthFirst()
                .relationships(RelTypes.CAMPAIGN, Direction.BOTH)
                .relationships(RelTypes.CO_OCCURANCE, Direction.BOTH)
                .evaluator(Evaluators.toDepth(10))
                .evaluator(Evaluators.excludeStartPosition())
                .uniqueness(Uniqueness.RELATIONSHIP_GLOBAL);
        return td.traverse(person);
    }

    // END SNIPPET: get-friends

    private void registerShutdownHook() {
        // Registers a shutdown hook for the Neo4j instance so that it
        // shuts down nicely when the VM exits (even if you "Ctrl-C" the
        // running example before it's completed)
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                graphDb.shutdown();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void deleteFileOrDirectory(final File file) {
        if (!file.exists()) {
            return;
        }

        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            for (File child : file.listFiles()) {
                deleteFileOrDirectory(child);
            }
        } else {
            file.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

/////////////////////// AND HERE IS THE OUTPUT ///////////////////////////////////

```
At depth 1 => (0)--[CAMPAIGN,1]-->(1)
 FurnitureShop-1---(furniture, 0.6)---(chair, 0.6)---(table, 0.6)----FurnitureShop-2


At depth 1 => (0)--[CAMPAIGN,2]-->(2)
 FurnitureShop-1---(furniture, 0.7)---(sofa, 0.7)----FurnitureShop-3


At depth 1 => (0)--[CO_OCCURANCE,0]-->(1)
 FurnitureShop-1---(coOccurence, 5.0)----FurnitureShop-2


At depth 2 => (0)--[CAMPAIGN,1]-->(1)<--[CO_OCCURANCE,3]--(2)
 FurnitureShop-3---(coOccurence, 4.0)----FurnitureShop-2

*************************************
**** Devide w.r.t maxVal = [RelationshipTypeToken[name:CO_OCCURANCE, id:0]=5.0, RelationshipTypeToken[name:CAMPAIGN, id:1]=0.7]And Normalized Values Are:*************
*************************************

At depth 1 => (0)--[CAMPAIGN,1]-->(1)
FurnitureShop-1---**(furniture, 0.8571428571428572)---(chair, 0.8571428571428572)---(table, 0.8571428571428572)**----FurnitureShop-2


At depth 1 => (0)--[CAMPAIGN,2]-->(2)
FurnitureShop-1---(furniture, 1.0)---(sofa, 1.0)----FurnitureShop-3


At depth 1 => (0)--[CO_OCCURANCE,0]-->(1)
FurnitureShop-1---(coOccurence, 1.0)----FurnitureShop-2


At depth 2 => (0)--[CAMPAIGN,1]-->(1)<--[CO_OCCURANCE,3]--(2)
FurnitureShop-3---(coOccurence, 0.8)----FurnitureShop-2


+++++++++++++NOW **WRONG VALUES** WILL BE PRINTED+++++++++++++++

At depth 1 => (0)--[CAMPAIGN,1]-->(1)
 FurnitureShop-1---**(furniture, 1.2244897959183676)---(chair, 1.2244897959183676)**---(table, 1.2244897959183676)----FurnitureShop-2


At depth 1 => (0)--[CAMPAIGN,2]-->(2)
 FurnitureShop-1---(furniture, 1.0)---(sofa, 1.0)----FurnitureShop-3


At depth 1 => (0)--[CO_OCCURANCE,0]-->(1)
 FurnitureShop-1---(coOccurence, 1.0)----FurnitureShop-2


At depth 2 => (0)--[CAMPAIGN,1]-->(1)<--[CO_OCCURANCE,3]--(2)
 FurnitureShop-3---(coOccurence, 0.8)----FurnitureShop-2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. try to remove the inner transactions, they don't help you,
2. when setting or printing out the values also print out the id's of nodes and rels so that you see, that you're actually looking at the same objects